# limit of $\lim_{x\to 1} x^\frac{1}{x-1}$

Tags: calculus

> $$\lim_{x\to 1} x^\frac{1}{x-1}$$

I am trying to understand the use of $\ln$ to find the limit (I know I can define $y=x-1$ and find the limit)

what should I do after this step? $\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{1}{x-1}\cdot \ln(x)$ and how did it change the limit (as I took the ln of the limit and changed the expression)

I can see that $\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{1}{x-1}\cdot \ln(x)=\lim_{x\to 1} \ln(x-1)' \cdot \ln(x)$

Comment: Try l'Hospital rule

Comment: Try to use slashes in fractional exponents; it's hard to understand the problem as is. ie:   $x^{1/(x-1)}$

Comment: @CTNT I can use l'Hospital  on this expression? I need to change it to  $\frac{infty}{infty}$ or $\frac{0}{0}$

Comment: Its $\frac{0}{0}$ isn't it?

Comment: **Hint** The logarithm of the function in the limit is $\frac{\log x}{x - 1}$; can you express the limit of this quantity as $x \to 1$ as the value of the derivative of a function at a particular point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is  a standard limit that 
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\ln x}{x-1}=1$$
Actually this quotient is but the rate of change of the ln function,, starting from $x=1$:
$$\frac{\ln x}{x-1}=\frac{\ln x-\ln 1}{x-1}\to (\ln)'(1)=1\enspace \text{as}\enspace x\to 1.$$
Thus $$\lim_{x\to1}x^{\tfrac1{x-1}}=\mathrm e.$$

Comment: but applying ln did not change the expression? isn't it like taking a square root or something?

Comment: ln is continuous, as is its inverse function. Furthermore, the very definition of $x^{\tfrac1{x-1}}$ is that it is $\mathrm e^{\tfrac{\ln x}{x-1}}$.

Comment: @gbox $e^x$ is continuous function so if you know that $\ln x^{1/(x-1)} \rightarrow 1$ then $x^{1/(x-1)} \rightarrow e$.

Comment: So because it is continuous and therefore it has an inverse function finding the limit of the inverse function is like finding the limit of the original function?

Comment: Not exactly: we find the limit of the log of the function, then taking the limit of the exponential (of the log of the function) we have the limit of the original function. This works because everyone is continuous.

Comment: so we say $e^{ln(limit)}$

Comment: Or more simply $f\circ f^{-1}=\text{id}$.

Comment: just to make sure I got it, if the limit we would find after using $\ln$ was 5 for example, the limit we original looked for is $e^5$?

Comment: Perfectly correct.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\dfrac{\ln x}{x-1}=\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\dfrac{(\ln x)'}{(x-1)'}=\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\dfrac{1/x}{1}=1$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to 1} x^\frac{1}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to 1} \left(1+\frac{x-1}1\right)^\frac{1}{x-1}=\lim_{y\to 0} \left(1+y\right)^\frac{1}{y}=e$$

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit more

Comment: There are two definitions for $e$. One is $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$, and the other is $\lim_{a\to 0} \left(1+a\right)^{\frac1a}$. Those two are same actually. I used the second one. Refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29

Comment: I meant to the expression in the middle

Comment: It's just $x=1+x-1=1+\frac{x-1}1$. I wrote it differently so that you can better see that $\frac{x-1}1$ and $\frac1{x-1}$ are reciprocals each other.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y = x^{1/(x-1)}$.

We wish to find $\lim\limits_{x \to 1}y$. Call this limit $L$.

Notice that $\ln(y) = \ln(x^{1/(x-1)}) = \dfrac{1}{x-1}\ln(x)$.

**Because** $\ln$ **is continuous at** $x = 1$, it follows that 
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 1}\ln(y) = \ln\left(\lim\limits_{x \to 1}y\right) = \ln(L)\text{.}$$
Furthermore, since $\ln(y) = \dfrac{\ln(x)}{x-1}$,
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 1}\ln(y) = \lim\limits_{x \to 1}\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x-1}\text{.}$$
There are several ways to evaluate this limit, but since you know L-Hospital:
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 1}\ln(y) =\lim\limits_{x \to 1}\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x-1} = \lim\limits_{x \to 1}\dfrac{1/x}{1} = 1\text{.}$$
**But**, as stated earlier,
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 1}\ln(y) = \ln(L)$$
so $\ln(L) = 1$, or $L = e$.